# pyenv - environment "activated", but python and pip not found

Tags: bash, pyenv

I suppose there is something wrong with my bash init scripts (like `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`). But let's start from beginning.

I can create and activate pyenv environment, but when I try to use python, I get error: `-bash: python: command not found`.
It looks like pyenv understands creation and swapping envorinments. I mean, it's probably not malformed. There is preview of my tries:

```
$ mkdir test-python-project
$ cd test-python-project/
$ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/vagrant/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.10
  3.7.10/envs/k-pkb-env
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.7.10 test-env
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpkwojcc1e
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (47.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (20.1.1)
$ pyenv activate test-env
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 to simulate the behavior.
(test-env) $ python
-bash: python: command not found
(test-env) $ pyenv local test-env
(test-env) $ cd ..
(test-env) $ pyenv deactivate
$ cd test-python-project/
(test-env) $ python
-bash: python: command not found
(test-env) $ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
(test-env) $ pyenv version
test-env (set by /home/vagrant/Work/test-python-project/.python-version)
```

I'm not sure how to configure bash init scripts, because in [pyenv readme](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout) they suggest using `.profile`, which I don't have.

So, there are my bash inits:

**.bashrc**

```
$ cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific environment
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ "$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:" ]]
then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
```

**.bash_profile**

```
$ cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

# PyEnv
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Some additional information:

**$PATH variable**

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/vagrant/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

It's a bit strange for me, because this additional paths added by pyenv doesn't seem to contain path to desired virtual environment:

```
$ ls /home/vagrant/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims
activate  deactivate
$ ls /home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin
pyenv
```

**`type python`**

```
$ type python
-bash: type: python: not found
```

**`which python`**

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/which: no python in (/home/vagrant/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin)
```

I tried also `pyenv rehash`, but also still no effect:

```
(test-env) [vagrant@centos test-python-project]$ pyenv rehash
(test-env) [vagrant@centos test-python-project]$ python
-bash: python: command not found
```

Comment: What doe `type python` print?

Comment: @RamanSailopal `.profile` is only used if neither `.bash_profile` nor `.bash_login` exists.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added the output of both `type python` and `which python`

Comment: Did you run `pyenv rehash` after installing new python version>?

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still no effect :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

READ THE PYENV GUIDE CAREFULLY.

You didn't follow pyenv's README guide correctly. The guide tells you put `PATH` related operation in `.bash_profile` or `.profile`. But `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in `.bashrc`.

Move `pyenv` init script from `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`.

```sh
# Put it in .bashrc

# PyEnv
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

### Extended Reading

You bash shell is not a login shell. `.bash_profile` is not sourced at all, which skip `pyenv init -`.

Bash initialization

1. **login** mode:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only the **first** one that exists)
2. **interactive non-login**:

   1. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   2. `~/.bashrc`
3. **non-interactive**:

   1. source file in `$BASH_ENV`

The default shell on Linux is a non-login, interactive shell. The default shell on macOS is a login, interactive shell.

There's also a [detailed explanation about the shell startup by flowblok](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)

[image]

### Ref

- [Unix shell initialization from pyenv wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization#shell-init-files)
- [Shell startup scripts](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)

Comment: Although your answer is a bit rude, I appreciate that. You helped me get into working solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With some help from @Simba, I managed to have my configuration correct:

**`.bash_profile`**

```
# .bash_profile

# !!! ITS IMPORTANT THESE LINES MUST BE BEFORE . ~/.bashrc
# PyEnv - only path-related
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
# !!! ITS IMPORTANT THESE LINES ABOVE MUST BE BEFORE . ~/.bashrc



# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
```

**`.bashrc`**

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific environment
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ "$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:" ]]
then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions

# PyEnv - commands
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```